# Forward to char and change inside the same char

Tags: key-bindings

Is there any way to bind `cI<char>` to forward to next  ocurrence and change inside `<char>`?

Having

```
[p]rint(arg)
```

, pressing `cI(` would result in

```
print(|)
```

, `[]` represents cursor in normal mode and `|` represents cursor in insert mode.

So in summary, `cI(` would represent a shortcut to a key sequence like this `f(ci(`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `cI<char><CR>`?

The LHS of a mapping is a static string. You can't have a "dynamic" mapping with, say, a placeholder character that gets replaced with whatever character the user types. I suppose you could brute-force it and enter mappings for all the relevant chars: `cIw`, `cIW`, `cI(`, etc. I'm guessing you're hoping for something better than that.

I can think of one way to get close to what you want. Create a function and mapping like these (you can put them in your *vimrc* file):

```
function! ChangeInsideChar()
    let l:char = input("Enter a character: ")
    exec 'normal! f' . l:char . 'di' . l:char
    startinsert
endfunction

nnoremap cI :call ChangeInsideChar()<CR>
```

When you hit `cI` in Normal mode a prompt will appear. Enter the appropriate character then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the magic will happen. Using your example, if at the prompt you entered <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> that will  delete the text inside the next set of parens and leave you in Insert mode.

You can enter these sequences pretty quickly so in effect this solution is like just adding one extra key press to your hoped for binding. Heck, I've already thought of a few ideas for using this general technique myself.

**Update:** Thanks to a pointer from [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/343/rich), [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14394/forward-to-char-and-change-inside-the-same-char/14396#comment24730_14396), we can *eliminate <kbd>Enter</kbd>* because Vim has a single char fetch function. Here's the new and improved function:

```
function! ChangeInsideChar()
    echomsg 'Enter a character '
    let l:mychar = nr2char(getchar())
    exec 'normal! f' . l:mychar . 'di' . l:mychar
    startinsert
endfunction
```

Comment: Using `getchar()` instead of `input(...)` gets even closer. (You also have to use `nr2char(l:char)` instead of `l:char` in the `execute` line.)

Comment: @Rich Oh, awesome. I wondered if there was a single char input function but hadn't gotten around to looking for it. I'll update my answer to incorporate that if you don't mind.